# Creating an iPhone View with multiple icons (such as Yelp, Old Facebook Launcher)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view, ios5

I was wondering what is the best approach for creating a UIview with multiple icons that go to different view controllers. I have seen an open source launcher code for creating such a view but I rather learn on what is the best practice for creating one from scratch? Is it a big image with code measuring the touch location? Are the buttons put dynamically? Is it a table with multiple cells in a row? ....

The Yelp launcher is also following the same pattern

[Facebook Launcher](http://images.brighthub.com/5f/1/5f1d7b5504bcc6f3df1ba5f6fd7a7c9e02c8fe7c_large.jpg)
[Yelp Launcher](http://images.brighthub.com/5f/1/5f1d7b5504bcc6f3df1ba5f6fd7a7c9e02c8fe7c_large.jpg)

Thanks,
Ross

Comment: What have you tried so far? From what I can tell, its just a UIScrollView with pagination enabled, with buttons as icons as the content view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the buttons dynamically. With each button being a seperate instance of `UIButton`. As  Richard J. Ross III suggested in a comment, you could for example put the various buttons in a `UIScrollView`.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
//set the contentSize property of scrollView to a multiple of the original frame size
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
button.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[scrollView addSubView:button];
```